# How to set up Sublime Text 3 for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublimetext3, babeljs, jsx

I'm trying to set up my Sublime Text 3 for React like the screenshots in [this link](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime), didn't succeed to make it though.

Maybe I have some extra packages or settings that would show my `index.js` syntax like below:

[image]

#### sublime-settings:

```
{
    "auto_complete": true,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic",
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": false,
    "font_face": "MONACO",
    "font_size": 16,
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "show_panel_on_build": true,
    "spell_check": true,
    "theme": "Adaptive.sublime-theme",
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
}
```

I also have these packages:

[image]

How do I do that?

(Thanks! I'm new to React/js/jsx)

Comment: I was using ST as a main IDE until around 2017 and I still use ST3 for its speed, but only for quickly hacking some small snippets, text files, etc. For serious development I started using VSCode. The experience is much better, I suggest you to give it a try. The ecosystem is much more developed around VSCode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best package I found for react/jsx on sublime was Naomi. It deals with syntax highlighting and has a lot of other features.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Naomi

Comment: No worries, if the syntax highlighting isn't working try removing some of the other packages, they can often conflict with each other.

Answer (score 15):

Use the Default JSX style of Sublime Text.

GoTo:

> View -> Syntax -> Javascript -> JSX

Alternatively you can select the syntax from the bottom right status bar menu of Sublime text.

Answer (score 2):

Open the command palette: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on MacOS/Linux, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on Windows

type `install`, select **Package Control: Install Package**

type `React`, select **ReactJS**

Comment: Deprecated in favor of babel/babel-sublime